# azure pipeline No test result files were found

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an azure pipeline to build and publish a c# project to a docker image.
everything works just fine but today I wanted to add a unit test this pipeline.

so I added the task for it.

as follow:

```
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '5.x'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'DotNet - Restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: $(project)
      noCache: true
      versioningScheme: 'off'
      vstsFeed: 'feed'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Run unit tests - $(Build.BuildNumber)"
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      arguments: '--no-build --configuration $(Build.BuildNumber)'
      projects: 'path/to/Tests.csproj'
      publishtestResults: true

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    name: 'DotnetPublish'
    displayName: 'dotnet - Publish'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: $(project)
      arguments: '-o publish/projectapi -c release'
      modifyOutputPath: false
      zipAfterPublish: false
      publishWebProjects: false

  - task: Docker@2
    name: 'dockerBuildAndPush'
    displayName: 'docker - Build & Push'
    inputs:
      repository: $(imageRepository)
      Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
      containerRegistry: ${{ variables.dockerRegistryServiceConnection }}
      buildContext: ${{ variables.buildContext }}
      tags: |
        $(Build.BuildNumber)
        latest
```

when I run the pipeline, on the test task, it take less than 2 second and it returns

```
##[warning]No test result files were found.
```

and if I head to the tests tab, I see the message that there are no tests to display.

Am I doing something wrong in my pipeline configuration?

thank you so much for any help

EDIT:
There are some update about this. The issue was related to the fact that I didn't have a build task for the test csproj.
When I implemented the task and run the pipeline. I got an error about a nuget package not found (private nuget). In my vsfeed in the devops panel, I can see that package exists, but for some reason the pipeline fails because it doesn't see that package.
Did this ever happened to anyone and knows a workaround?

Comment: Is the tests .csproj being included in the $(project) var?

Comment: No is not. Do I have to include it? Because my test, generate random data and checks the results.

Comment: I don't have much experience with AzurePipelines but I would include it and see if works.

Comment: No it doesn't work. same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the `--no-build` from the arguments. Nothing in the pipeline before it appears to run the build. You also may need to make sure that your `dotnet restore` command is restoring the packages for the test project. (I can't tell from if the restore for `$(project)` would or not)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and advice. Is it compiling now. But I am back to the error I was getting at the beginning. I get those errors. `.dll is invalid. Please use the /help option to check the list of valid arguments.` related to the csproj I restored and build. the other error is `##[warning]No test result files were found`.. thank you so much for any help you can provide

Comment: Is it working now, I forgot to remove the --no-build. Thank you so much my friend

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was also was related to the .Net Restore task. The 'projects' property was originally set to the web.csproj file, so the Tests project was not restoring. I switched out the 'projects' value to my entire solution file and the warning went away.

```html
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'DotNet - Restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: './EntireProject.sln'
      noCache: true
      versioningScheme: 'off'
      vstsFeed: 'feed'
```